# Can an orc get Sting or Orcrist as a sacrifice gift?

Tags: nethack

As the title says; if you're playing as an orc, is it possible to get Sting or Orcrist as a sacrifice gift?

If so, I want to `name` them to get rid of the chance of getting them. If not, I don't want to `name` them, in order to improve my sacrifice gift chances.

Vanilla Nethack 3.6.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can never be gifted an artifact that hates your current race. Orcs can't receive Sting or Orcrist, and elves will never receive Grimtooth. (For this reason, an elf can always name Sting and Orcrist to be guaranteed Stormbringer as the first gift.)

Source reference: https://github.com/NetHack/NetHack/blob/NetHack-3.6.1_Release/src/artifact.c#L157